# Open sets and open balls in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

**Theorem**. Suppose $(X,d)$ be a metric space. 
If $U\subseteq X$ is an open set, then for all elements $a\in U$, there exists a real number $\delta> 0$ such that  $B(a;r)\subseteq U$.

---

I tried to prove the contrapositive using the nested set property:

**Proof**. Suppose that there exists some element $a\in U$ such that $B(a,\delta)\nsubseteq U$ for all $\delta > 0$. 
Then it must be true that $B(a,\delta)\cap (X\setminus U)$ is nonempty for all $\delta > 0$. 
For all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let

$$A_n=B\Bigl(a,\frac{1}{n+1}\Bigr)\cap (X\setminus U)$$

and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $x_n\in A_n$, and by the nested set property,

$$\bigcap\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}A_n =\{a\}$$
which shows that $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $X\setminus U$ which converges to an element $a\notin X \setminus U$, and therefore $X\setminus U$ is not a closed set.

---

I'd just like some verification/feedback, or tips on how else this could be proved.

Comment: How have you defined an open set? The usual definition is what you’re trying to prove - every point has an open neighbourhood contained in the set.

Comment: Yes, I know the definition of an open set, but this theorem is assuming the sequential definition of closed as the definition of closed, and the definition of open being that the complement is closed.

Comment: Looks right.   $a$ is then a limit point of $X\setminus U$ not in $X\setminus U$...